# Generar archivo minificado y "normal" en Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Estoy intentando generar un archivo css minificado y "normal" con `gulp-clean-css` de la siguiente manera:

```
const css = () => {
return src('src/scss/index.scss')
.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
.pipe(autoprefixer())
.pipe(rename('app.css'))
.pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
.pipe(dest('dist/css'))
}
```

El cual nada mas genera el archivo minificado, pero no tengo idea de como generar el otro "normal" sin minificar. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Al final es posible utilizar multiples `.dest()` por lo que al final quedaria asi

```
// "Normal"
.pipe(rename('app.css'))
.pipe(dest('dist/css'))
// Minificado
.pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
.pipe(rename('app-min.css'))
.pipe(dest('dist/css'))
```